# Grep and Regex an HTML File

Tags: html, unix, grep, cat

I have an HTML file with thousands of lines, but something is repeated.

```
CODE=12345-ABCDE-12345-ABCDE</div>...<!--This line goes on for hundreds of characters-->
```

Now, The line starts with "CODE="  every time, and the length of the code is the same every time. The following 28 characters are either letters, numbers, or dashes.

```
cat mysite.html | grep "CODE="
```

But I'd like a regex to display everything on the line BEFORE`</div>`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cut` instead:

```
cat myfile.html | cut -c 6-28
```

This shows the characters 6 - 28 of each line. This makes use of the fact that the length of `CODE=` is known as well as the length of the code that follows.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! This worked like a charm:
`cat mysite.html | grep "CODE=" | cut -c 6-29`

Comment: @Goodies You don't need to use `cat` here. `grep "CODE=" mysite.html` is the same as `cat mysite.html | grep "CODE="`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` also:

```
sed -rn 's@^(CODE=[A-Za-z0-9\-]{23})</div>.*@\1@p' file
```

Match any line staring with `CODE=` followed by 23 characters containing `either letters, numbers, or dashes`, followed by `</div>`